# Klazuka Kal Scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, calendar

I am integrating Klazuka Kal into my iPhone app and need more space to view the events which display in the tableview under the calendar. My main thought it, maybe I can have it so that when scrolling the tableview the calendar scrolls with it so that its not constantly in the way.

If anyone can help me achieve this or has any other ideas I would much appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of your exact use case but bearing in mind UITableView conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate you could implement the following callback....

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)tableView {
    calendar.contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
}
```

...or similar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No luck! The calendar is a view (no content offset) and the tableview is of course a tableview, but I just can't get it working. If you could take a look and see if you could achieve it in his source code I would super appreciate it (code is identical to mine): https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Comment: @adam i did, but its not working.  i Mean how to reload data in kal calendar page.